# Best way to implement a workflow based on a series of asynchronous ASIHTTPRequests in iOS?

Tags: objective-c, ios, asynchronous, asihttprequest, objective-c-blocks

I've been fighting and fighting for some time with a decent way to handle a workflow based on a series of asynchronous ASIHTTPRequests (I am using queues).  So far it seems to have eluded me and I always end with a hideous mess of delegate calls and spaghetti code exploding all over my project.

It works as follows:

1. Download a list of items (1 single ASIHTTPRequest, added to a queue).
2. The items retrieved in step 1 need to be stored.
3. Each item, from 1 is then parsed, queuing a 1 ASIHTTPRequest per item, for it's sub-items.
4. Each of the requests from step 3 are processed and the sub-items stored.

I need to be able to update the UI with the progress %age and messages.
I'm unable for the life of me to figure out a clean/maintainable way of doing this.

I've looked at the following links:

- [Manage Multiple Asynchronous Requests in iOS with ASINetworkQueue](http://ygamretuta.me/2011/09/20/manage-multiple-asynchronous-request-in-ios-with-asinetworkqueue/)
- [Sync-Async Pair Pattern Easy Concurrency on iOS](http://blog.jayway.com/2011/04/28/sync-asyn-pair-pattern-easy-concurrency-on-ios/)

But either I'm missing something, or they don't seem to adequately describe what I'm trying to achieve.

Could I use blocks?

Comment: might I suggest looking into an alternative library such as https://github.com/gowalla/AFNetworking, especially considering the blog post this week stating that development efforts have stopped on ASIHTTPRequest

Comment: Will take a look at that looks like a nice alternative to ASIHTTPRequest, but I still see no additional information that will help me get round my problem of all this asynchronous stuff and delegates making messy spaghetti code?  Any further help appreciated :D

Comment: ASIHTTPRequests library seems to be deprecated - http://allseeing-i.com/

Comment: you can use blocks with ASI.  see here: http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use#using_blocks

Comment: As I've said, ASIHTTPRequest seems to be less of the problem for me.  It's the **implementation of the strict workflow without getting spaghetti code** that's my bigger problem, and I don't seem to be able to find any good answers.  Everything tends to just deal with a _single request_ or _multiple standalone requests_.  **I need a solution/tutorial/pointers on how to handle multiple linked requests, asynchronously _and_ cleanly.** The net seems to have less, if any, of those. :(

Comment: cpjolicoeur, I see I can use blocks, but that is one request's response being handled in a block, nowhere near what I'm after.  Or can I just nest them, which is even more filthy in my mind? :(  Sorry to be a pain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see myself facing a quite similar issue as I got the exercise to work on a app using a set of async http and ftp handlers in a set of process and workflows. 
I'm not aware about ASIHTTP API but I assume I did something similar.
I defined a so called RequestOperationQueue which can for example represent all request operations of a certain workflow. Also I defined several template operations for example FTPDownloadOperation.  And here comes the clue. I implemented all these RequestOperations more or less accroding to the idea of http://www.dribin.org/dave/blog/archives/2009/05/05/concurrent_operations/. Instead of implementing the delegate logic in the operation itself I implemented sth like callback handlers specialized for the different protocols (http, ftp, rsync, etc) providing a status property for the certain request which can be handled by the operation via KVO.
The UI can be notified about the workflow for example by a delegate protocol for RequestOperationQueue. for example didReceiveCallbackForRQOperation:(RequestOperation) rqo.
From my point of view the coding of workflows including client-server operations gets quite handy with this approach.